# cordova console.log - can I set "Tag" and "Level"?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, logging

I am using Javascript Cordova, and reading the logs in `Android Device Monitor` but everything is coming out level "D" and with the same tag "`CordovaLog`"...  given the sheer volume of messages `Android Device Monitor` this is pretty basic, (albeit it is better than nothing), is there a way to set the "priority" of a `console.log` as Java does, with `Log.E(TAG,"string")` or  `Log.W(TAG,"string")` so that I can log errors as "E" errors or "W" warnings and is there anyway of tagging it to a certain filter?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this useful plugin
[cordova-plugin-console](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console)

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-console
```

but it doesn't support TAGS only colors. it is an android limitation